# knitr set_parent() always outputs NULL despite echo=FALSE

Tags: r, knitr

I have a master document

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<main>>=
  a <- 20
  b <- 30
@

<<child-demo, child='child.Rnw', eval=TRUE>>=
@

\end{document}
```

and a corresponding child document

```
<<set-parent, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
set_parent('mwe.Rnw')
@

<<child-code>>=
  a + b
@
```

When processing the file, I get the following output

```
a <- 20
b <- 30

## NULL

a + b
## [1] 50
```

Using `\Sexpr{set_parent('mwe.Rnw')}` does not produce the ugly `##NULL` in the output, but I would prefer declaring the parent via a chunk, as I try to only use `\Sexpr{}` outside of chunks

Comment: Why don't you post a bug report on https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues?sort=updated&state=open ? The author of knitr is very responsive.

Comment: @user946850 I'm not 100% certain it's a bug and I know yihui is quite active here as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider wrapping the call with `invisible`:

```
> invisible(1)
> invisible(1) == 1
[1] TRUE
```

Hence, `invisible(set_parent('mwe.Rnw'))` should work without printing `NULL`. I think this is  responsibility of `set_parent`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Missed that command up to now. I'll accept in a few days just in case there's a better answer. Feel free to poke me if I forget though :)

Comment: I have already used `invisible()` in `set_parent()`: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/R/utils.R#L139 I'll look into it. Sounds like there is a bug either in `evaluate` or `knitr`... Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, it turns out to be my bug; I should have used `return(invisible(NULL))` instead of `return()` there. Will be fixed in a minute.

Comment: Just as an add-on: ``<<set-parent, cache=FALSE, include=FALSE>>=`` will also work to suppress all of the output of the chunk.

Answer (score 2):

Although I have [fixed the problem](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/607b03ed1dcb94ac321bb7c9f393f684786cf7aa) in `knitr` 1.0.6, the answer by user946850 is essential, so I recommend that one to be accepted as the answer. For now, you can [install](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#installation) the development version.